# The value of a parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length

Tags: apex, formula-field

I am receiving the following error when I create the following formula field on activities:

> The value of a parameter contains a character that is not allowed or
>   the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character
>   from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit.

Here is the formula - Is this because I am using WHOID?

```
IF(
 Demo_Set__c = true ,
CASESAFEID(WhoId) ,
"")
```

Comment: What type did you declare this formula as producing? (I.e. the formula field)

Comment: @PhilW it is a text field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NULL instead of "".

```
IF(Demo_Set__c, CASESAFEID(WhoId), NULL)
```

Passing in an empty string for an ID value isn't allowed, so that may be the source of your problem.